# i need to control rgb leds brightness using phototransistor plus transistor and at the same time send light value to analog pin on Arduino

Tags: arduino, led, transistors, phototransistor

[image]
Schematic is missing led resistor.

i need to control rgb leds brightness using phototransistor plus transistor and at the same time send light value to analog pin on .I'm not sure where do I go from here and what kind of components I need to make this work.

Comment: I think you have some fairly fundamental misunderstandings of how transistors, resistors, and GPIO pins work. You would do well to start with simple Arduino tutorials, as well as basic electrical engineering texts, and build your skills from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Arduino read the photo transistor.

You need an RGB LED driver, like the  [On-Semi NCP5623](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP5623-D.PDF) or something like a [WS2812](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf) with RGB LED and driver.

You can probably do without the photo transistor because you will know how bright each LED is when you set the brightness.